# Broadcast of Intent has timed out via system broadcast

Tags: android

On my Android App, when LOCALE is changed I'm trying to invoke a JobIntentService to prevent ANR, but before even my BroadcastReceiver is invoked, it gets timed out(**no ANR**).

**Error**

> E ActivityManager: Reason: Broadcast of Intent {
> act=android.intent.action.LOCALE_CHANGED flg=0x11200010
> cmp=com.company.locale.LocaleChangeReceiver } has timed out via system
> broadcast.

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<!-- Listen to locale change -->
        <receiver android:name="com.company.locale.LocaleChangeReceiver"
                  android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.LOCALE_CHANGED"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Answer (score -1):

You should not set `android:exported` to false. This will limit broadcast receiver's external exposure. If it is set to false receiver is intended only for **application-internal** use.

> Note: This attribute is not the only way to limit a broadcast
> receiver's external exposure. You can also use a permission to limit
> the external entities that can send it messages

Comment: it didn't solve even when i changed it to android:exported="true". I still get timed out via system broadcast. Even the log from first line from LocaleChangeReceiver.onReceive() too doesn't get printed.

Comment: I guess that your onReceive() is taking too long to complete, resulting in this error. Read this section https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver#onReceive(android.content.Context,%20android.content.Intent)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it might work for someone probably, but for my case it is not a root cause because I had true always there